# Remove a file from the pull request

Tags: git

I have made all my changes on a branch created form master and then raised a pull request on the repository and got a review comment form my team mate about reverting a file.

Which is not actually changed by me, seems like my editor atom settings has added a new line at the end but for some reason i try to revert it twice. I get the same issue either by deleting one line extra or adding a space not sure how to resolve this issue.

[image: repo screen shot attached]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can just revert the file by following the commands below.
- Update your local git repo.

`git fetch`

- will show you the status of your branch

`git status`

- then to revert a specific file. make sure i have got your file path
  correct

`git checkout origin/master repository-data/webfiles/src/main/resources/site/freemaker/include/imports.ftl`

- The file should be reverted and added too

`git commit -m "commit message"`

- git push to the upstream

`git push`